# Animating Material Nodes in the Game Engine

Tags: python, animation, materials, game-engine, node-editor

Is there a way to access object properties or any other properties from the material node editor?
Can a value assigned in Material Node editor be changed using python while the game is running?

Comment: Object color can be changed using python and accessed in the node editor.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will have to test the possibilities of this.

Comment: There are many possibilities, but I wish there were more per-object values. 3 floats isn't very many, and packing data in there is not much fun.

Comment: Oh man, that's the fun part for me :)

Comment: I just started testing this and can't find a way to access object color in the Node Editor.

Comment: I'll do a proper answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use Object Color. This can be accessed both by python and by the node editor, and gives you access to three per-object values.

In UPBGE you can access object color using the ObjectData node:
[image]

In normal BGE you have to create a shadeless white material with object color enabled. Remember to make the diffuse color white, otherwise the color is multiplied (by default) by 0.8!

[image]

Slightly unclear from the image is that there are two materials: the shadeless object color one, and the node one.